# Representaility of morphism of stacks for schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, algebraic-stacks

I have seen two definitions of representability of a morphism of stacks, which should be at least compatible with the definition of a morphism of categories fibered in groupoids.

1. [(Representable morphism of categories fibred in groupoids)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02Y4). Let $\mathcal C$ be a category. Let $\mathcal X,\mathcal Y$ be categories fibred in groupoids over $\mathcal C$. Let $F:\mathcal X\to \mathcal Y$ be a $1$-morphism. We say $F$ is representable, if for every $S\in Ob(\mathcal C)$ and any $G:\mathcal C/S\to\mathcal Y$ the category fibred in groupoids $(\mathcal C/S)\times_{\mathcal Y}S\to S$ is representable.
2. (Representable morphism of stacks). We say that a morphism of stacks $ f : \mathcal X \to \mathcal Y $ is representable if for all S-schemes $ U $ and morphisms $ y : U \to \mathcal Y $, the fiber product $\mathcal  X \times_{\mathcal Y} U $ is an algebraic space.
3. [(Representable morphism of stacks)](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/notes/moduli-red-harvard.pdf). We say that a morphism of stacks $ f : \mathcal X \to \mathcal Y $ is representable if for all $S$-schemes $ U $ and morphisms $ y : U \to \mathcal Y $, the fiber product $ \mathcal X \times_{\mathcal Y} U $ is a scheme.

How can we reconcile these 3 definitions? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: 2. and 3. are genuinely different in general. Just take $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathrm{Spec} k$ an algebraic space over a field $k$ which is not a scheme. Then this is representable in the sense of 2., but not 3. For stacks definition 2. is the right one in general; sometimes authors refer to 3. as "strongly representable" or "schematic" to differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just too long for a comment. So, writing as an answer. It turns out that, one may not be able to see the correspondence between these three definitions as one of them is **stated wrongly**.

You have mentioned in the question the following:

1. [(Representable morphism of categories fibred in groupoids)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02Y4). Let $\mathcal C$ be a category. Let $\mathcal X,\mathcal Y$ be categories fibred in groupoids over $\mathcal C$. Let $F:\mathcal X\to \mathcal Y$ be a $1$-morphism. We say $F$ is representable, if for every $S\in Ob(\mathcal C)$ and any morphism  of categories fibered in groupoids $G:\mathcal C/S\to\mathcal Y$, the $2$-fiber product  $(\mathcal C/S)\times_{\mathcal Y}S\to S$ is representable.

This definition wrongly stated (I am hoping it was a typo). Observe that your definition of representability of $F$ depends only with the category $\mathcal{Y}$ and nothing do with neither the category $\mathcal{X}$ or the map $F:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$

Correct definition of representable morphism of categories fibered in groupoids is the following:

> Let $\mathcal C$ be a category. Let $\mathcal X,\mathcal Y$ be categories fibred in groupoids over $\mathcal C$. Let $F:\mathcal X\to \mathcal Y$ be a $1$-morphism. We say $F$ is representable, if for every $S\in Ob(\mathcal C)$ and any morphism $G:\mathcal C/S\to\mathcal Y$ of categories fibered in groupoids, the projection map $(\mathcal C/S)\times_{G,\mathcal Y,F}\mathcal{X}\to (\mathcal C/S)$ is representable.

By "$(\mathcal C/S)\times_{G,\mathcal Y,F}\mathcal{X}\to (\mathcal C/S)$ is representable", it means that the  $2$-fibered product $(\mathcal C/S)\times_{G,\mathcal Y,F}\mathcal{X}$ is representable by **an object of $\mathcal{C}$**; that is  $\mathcal C/S)\times_{G,\mathcal Y,F}\mathcal{X}\cong (\mathcal{C}/T)$ for some $T\in \text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and that the morphism $(\mathcal{C}/T)\rightarrow (\mathcal{C}/S)$ is induced from an arrow $T\rightarrow S$ (or $S\rightarrow T$??, make a guess) in $\mathcal{C}$.

I hope you will be able to prove this definition of $(1)$ is related the definition of $(3)$. I will give more details about this if there is still some difficulty.

There are two notions of representability:

1. Given a category $\mathcal{C}$ and an object $S$ of $\mathcal{C}$, one can associate a category fibered in groupoiods over $\mathcal{C}$, namely the functor $(\mathcal{C}/S)\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. Now, an arbitrary category fibered in groupoids over $\mathcal{C}$, say $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ is said to be **representable by an object of $\mathcal{C}$** if there is an object $S$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and an isomrophism $\mathcal{F}\cong (\mathcal{C}/S)$. This is the situtation of your point $3$.
2. It turns out that there are other interesting categories fibered in groupoids over $\mathcal{C}$. If $\mathcal{C}$ is $Sch/S$, we have algebraic spaces. If $\mathcal{C}$ is the category $\text{Man}$, we have what are called Lie groupoids. Given a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$, one can assocaite a category fibered in groupoids $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. Now, given a category fibered in groupoids $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$, we can ask if this $F$ is **representably by such a special category fibered in groupoids**, that is a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ and an isomorphism $\mathcal{F}\cong B\mathcal{G}$. This is the situtation of your point $2$.